# Composition of adjunctions in a (weak) 2-category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

Let $(f_1, g_1, \varepsilon_1, \eta_1)$ and $(f_2, g_2, \varepsilon_2, \eta_2)$ be adjunctions in a (weak) 2-category. Then there is an adjunction $(f_2 \circ f1, g1 \circ g2, \varepsilon, \eta)$. I can figure out how to define $\varepsilon$ (resp., $\eta$) by inserting appropriately the unitors and associators between $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ (resp., $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$).

Although I know how to prove the counit-unit equations in the special case of the 2-category of categories (See for instance [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315013/how-to-prove-adjunctions-compose-via-units-and-counits/1315042#1315042)), I cannot figure out how to prove them in the general case.

Could someone spell out the commutative diagrams or provide with a reference where it is done in full?

It is stated in Section 2.1 of *Review of the elements of 2-categories* (Kelly and Street, 1974), but there is unfortunately no proof there.

Comment: By the way, not many authors prove statements of this kind for bicategories as opposed to 2-categories because it’s not necessary. Instead, one can prove the coherence theorem once and for all, and then any statement invariant under equivalence of bicategories, such as that your triangle identity diagrams commute, may be proved in a 2-category. That’s not to say this isn’t a reasonable exercise to want to do, of course.

Comment: @KevinCarlson The coherence theorem states that any *formal diagram* in a bicategory is commutative, right? But a formal diagram cannot by definition include the 2-cells $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$.

Comment: A sometimes more useful interpretation is that there is an equivalence between any bicategory and a 2-category, and better yet the equivalence from the 2-category is a strict 2-functor which is a split epimorphism. Thus you can compose your adjunctions by mapping them into the 2-category, composing there, and mapping back down; the split nature of the map back ensures you’ve now got a composed adjunction between exactly the two adjunctions you started with. Again, of course this is a lot for this problem, but if it sounds interesting I recommend Lack’s 2-categories companion.

Comment: @KevinCarlson That's interesting indeed. But sometimes category theory seems too circular for my taste.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Certainly there’s no formally circular reasoning here. It’s true that seemingly simple statements are often most conveniently proved with some powerful background results, but category theory is surely not unique in that.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Of course, I wouldn't dare to claim there is circular reasoning. I only wrote it "seems" so. This feeling (this is only that) comes from the fact that it is too often impossible to find sources with proofs not relying on "powerful background results". And it applies recursively those powerful results. I believe the mathematician community relies on sound foundations, but I have a hard time finding them. This question is an example.

Answer (score 3):

Analogously to the case of Sets in 1-category theory, it’s often enough to prove a statement for categories and apply the Yoneda embedding. This maps an adjunction in $K$ to an adjunction in the 2-category of 2-functors $K^{op}\to Cat$. Since the 2-Yoneda embedding is 2-fully faithful, it’s enough to prove the triangle identities for the composition in the latter 2-category. And here the definition is given levelwise by the definition in Cat, so if you can prove the triangle identities in Cat, you’ve proved them in $K$!

Comment: But my question is about a direct proof. Your answer is certainly interesting but I hope making a detour via the 2-Yoneda lemma (whose proof must be far more involved than a direct proof here) could be avoided.

Comment: @Bob Sure, that’s fair. Proofs via Yoneda are just so frequently helpful that I wanted to point out the option.

Answer (score 2):

In a 2-category a 2-cell $\alpha : U \Rightarrow V$ can be whiskered with a 1-cell $F$ on the right or on the left (of course, domains and codomains must match appropriately), to give $\alpha  *F$ and $F * \alpha$ (refer to Borceux I for the notation and the properties of whiskering, or "Review of the elements of 2-categories", by Kelly and Street).

The whiskering of a 2-cell $\alpha$ with a composition of functors $HK$ satisfies $\alpha * HK = (\alpha *H)*K $, and similarly $(\beta \circ \alpha)*H = (\beta *H)\circ (\alpha *H)$. [1]

The whiskering operation allows you to state the zig-zag identities for the co/unit of an adjunction: if $F\dashv G$, then $(\epsilon * F ) \circ (F * \eta) = 1_F$ and $(G * \epsilon)\circ (\eta * G)=1_G$.

Now for the proof: the counit of the composite adjunction $F = F_2F_1\dashv G_1G_2 =G$ is the 2-cell $F_2F_1G_1G_2 \overset{F_2 * \epsilon_1 * G_2}\Rightarrow F_2G_2 \overset{\epsilon_2}\Rightarrow 1$, and the unit is $1 \overset{\eta_1}\Rightarrow G_1F_1 \overset{G_1 *\eta_2 * F_1}\Rightarrow G_1G_2F_2F_1$.

I'll just start half of the proof :-) go on yourself!

$$
\begin{align*}
(\epsilon * F ) \circ (F * \eta) &= ((\epsilon_2 \circ (F_2 * \epsilon_1 * G_2))*F)\circ (F * ((G_1 *\eta_2 * F_1)\circ \eta_1)) \\
[1]&=\epsilon_2F_2F_1 \circ F_2\epsilon_1G_2F_2F_1 \circ F_2F_1G_2\eta_2F_1\circ F_2F_1\eta_1
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I understand all of that. But my question is about where to put the unitors and associators. Unfortunately, those are left implicit in your answer.

Comment: So you're talking about adjunctions in a *bi*category!

Comment: By "2-category" I meant "weak 2-category". I thought it was obvious since I mention unitors and associators. I will edit my question. Was your answer about strict 2-categories?

Comment: Indeed, on page 141 of Gray's "Formal Category Theory: Adjointness for 2-Categories", Gray writes that "*in the bicategory case, appropriate instances of the isomorphisms [...] must be inserted*". I tried to do it but failed. And I cannot find anyone who has done it.

Comment: It was late night in my timezone, and by default I'm used to call 2-category a strict one, and bicategory a weak one. Well, ok, let me think :)